# Custom expanding UITableViewCell has a glitch?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

Here's the [glitch](http://www.gfycat.com/DownrightDampBlackrussianterrier). As you can see when I push the custom `UITableViewCell SummaryCell` out of the view of the app the cell glitches and doesn't put the `UILabels` `dayOfTheWeek` and `totalAmountSpent` in their proper places. But if you click on the glitchy cell, it returns to normal.

Here are some of the methods of the`UITableViewController SummaryTableViewController` that I used to create the custom cell `summaryCell` :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Create day of week cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("summaryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SummaryCell
    let day = dayOfWeek[indexPath.row]

    let height = CGFloat(55)
    let dayOfWeekWidth = CGFloat(80)
    cell.dayOfWeek.text = day.rawValue.uppercaseString
    cell.dayOfWeek.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dayOfWeekWidth, height)
    cell.dayOfWeek.backgroundColor = colorOfDay[day]

    cell.totalAmountSpent.text = "$\(totalSpentPerDay[indexPath.row])"
    cell.totalAmountSpent.frame = CGRectMake(cell.dayOfWeek.frame.maxX + 1, 0, view.bounds.width - dayOfWeekWidth, height)
    cell.totalAmountSpent.backgroundColor = colorOfDay[day]
    cell.totalAmountSpentView.backgroundColor = colorOfDay[day]

    cell.heightOfMainView.constant = normalCellHeight 
    //^I have this to make sure the height of the cell is the same as 
    //the height of the mainView in the nib file `summaryCell` so that 
    //when the table loads intially, only the mainView of the `summaryCell` shows up.

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if expandedCellPaths.contains(indexPath){
        let index = expandedCellPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
        expandedCellPaths.removeAtIndex(index!)
    }else{
        expandedCellPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    //old trick to animate cell expand/collapse
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let expandedCellHeight = normalCellHeight*2
    if expandedCellPaths.contains(indexPath){
        return expandedCellHeight
    }else{
        return normalCellHeight
    }
}
```

This is [the nib file & its constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5sVx.png) corresponding to my custom `UITableViewCell SummaryCell`

My 2 best guess as to why this is happening are *(1)* the constraints in my nib file `summaryCell` or *(2)* the lines in my `UITableViewConroller SummaryTableViewController`:

If anyone could tell me how I can fix this glitch it would be greatly appreciated!
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually never mind! I realized my error! I just needed to delete these  lines in `tableView(:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
    let height = CGFloat(55)
    let dayOfWeekWidth = CGFloat(80)
    cell.dayOfWeek.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dayOfWeekWidth, height)
    cell.totalAmountSpent.frame = CGRectMake(cell.dayOfWeek.frame.maxX + 1, 0, view.bounds.width - dayOfWeekWidth, height)
```